# Python in Atom: Cannot import libraries using the "as" statement [Ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: python, pandas, atom-editor

I have a problem using Atom in Ubuntu 16.04 for some Python code I'm working at. I have already installed Script. Every time I try to `import pandas as pd` the command works, but only takes `pandas` as name, instead of `pd`.

Importing data with: `pd.read_csv( ... )` thus gives me the following error: `NameError: name 'pd' is not defined`.

In other editors (such as Spyder) I don't have any problem.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: The error is: `NameError: name 'pd' is not defined`.
In other words, it gets the `import pandas` part, but not the `as pd` one, and I don't understand why.

Comment: is it giving error while importing or while using? and is it causing only for pandas?

Comment: It gives error when I run the `pd.read_csv`.

Same problem with all the packages. The "brief names" are causing problems

Comment: Hi using the same editor on 16.04 Ubuntu. Does not give any error.